# Как правильно сделать всплывающее окно jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка, мобильная-разработка

Вопрос более глубокий. У меня есть код всплывающих окон:

```js
function box_info(id,value){
    $(".info-"+id).show();
    $(".info-"+id).css("display","block");
    $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
    if(value == 'close'){
        $(".info-"+id).hide();
        $(".info-"+id).css("display","none");
        $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
    }
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        if ($(".info-"+id).has(e.target).length === 0){
            $(".info-"+id).hide();
            $(".info-"+id).css("display","none");
            $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
        }
    });
};
```

```css
body{
    height: 1000px;  
}
#info{
    overflow:auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99997;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#info-box{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 99998; 
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-animation: info-top 0.35s ease-in-out;
    animation: info-top 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='info' class='info-1' style='display: none;'>
    <div id='info-box'>
        Первый блок. Много текста и блоков.
    </div>
</div>
<div id='info' class='info-2' style='display: none;'>
    <div id='info-box'>
        Второй блок. Много текста и блоков.
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick='box_info(1);'>Открыть первый блок</button>
<button onclick='box_info(2);'>Открыть второй блок</button>
```

**Проблема в скролле.**

1. Открыв первую или вторую всплывашку скролл блока исчезает и остается
   лишь скролл от body, при следующем открытии противоположной
   всплывашки и при клике на сам блок появляется скролл того и другого.
   Нужно чтобы появлялся лишь от body.
2. Плохо знаю адаптацию, но на андроид 2.3 fixed просто ужасно
   отображается и блок не скролиться.

Как можно это обойти, кроме того чтобы покупать новый телефон?

Comment: Андроид 2.3? Серьезно? Вам действительно необходима поддержка этих устройств? Казалось бы, уже все от них отказались и процент мизерный остался. Это как IE6 поддерживать в наше время.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Ну допустим не смотреть на андроид. Проблема еще есть в самом скролле. Я 100% уверен что написал код криво, но не знаю как правильно(

Comment: не могли бы вы уточнить, что должно происходить при клике в модальном окне? по коду выходит, что окно должно спрятаться. это так?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Извините, но что-то этот блок закрывается при клике на форму внутри этого блока. То есть при клике на чистый блок не закрывается, все норм, вот всунул форму с input и при фокусе блок закрылся

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Заметил, что весь текст в тегах. Убрал <span> от текста и блок не закрывается по клику на него. Но так не катит(

Comment: поправил код ответа. Полезное изменение внутри функции $('.popup-window').on('click'. Во всплывашки добавил блоки для проверки клика по вложенным в окно элементам, они вам не нужны.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Оперативно) Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема была в том, что вы при каждом клике на кнопку вешали слушатель события на $(document). Т.е., после первого нажатия на кнопку слушатель один и код при mouseup выполняется один раз. После второго - добавляется еще один и код уже выполняется дважды. Ну и так далее.

Но если вы просто вынесете в своем коде функцию - обработчик mouseup из функции box_info - появится ошибка, не определена переменная id. Поэтому я немного изменил код, избавившись от необходимости в id. Я определил всплывающим окнам общий класс и обработчик единый.

Насколько я вас понял, всплывающее окно должно закрываться при клике на сером фоне. Предложенное мною решение, на мой взгляд, некрасиво, но я не придумал ничего лучше в рамках текущей верстки. Зато работает правильно.

```js
function box_info(id,value){
    var $target = $("#info-"+id);     
 if(value == 'close'){
     $target.hide();
     $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
 } else {
            $target.show();
     $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
        }

};
$('.popup-window').on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('info-box') && !$(e.target).parents('.info-box').length){
        $(this).hide();
        $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    height: 1000px;  
}
.popup-window{
    display: none;
    overflow:auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99997;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.info-box{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 99998; 
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-animation: info-top 0.35s ease-in-out;
    animation: info-top 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='info-1' class='popup-window'>
    <div class='info-box'>
        Первый блок. Много текста и блоков.
        <div style="width:200px;height:30px;background:red;">красный блок</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='info-2' class='popup-window'>
    <div class='info-box'>
        Второй блок. Много текста и блоков.
        <div style="width:200px;height:30px;background:green;">зеленый блок</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick='box_info(1);'>Открыть первый блок</button>
<button onclick='box_info(2);'>Открыть второй блок</button>
```

Comment: А на чем вешайте закрывашку? Нужно как то на фон.

Comment: Изменил ответ и код в нем. Попробуйте. Обратите внимание, что на этот раз я исправил id и классы элементов. В первый раз я не обратил внимания, как вы используете id. Нельзя использовать один и тот же id на разных элементах! Это УНИКАЛЬНЫЙ идентификатор. Он должен быть один на странице. И css через id тоже нужно стараться писать поменьше. Ничего критичного, но лучше использовать для этой цели классы.